# allocate_shared when exceptions are banned

Tags: c++, exception, allocator

Is it possible to use `allocate_shared` in an environment where exceptions are prohibited (`fno-exceptions`), and allocators return `nullptr` instead of throwing on allocation failure? This means having a wrapper around `allocate_shared` that returns an empty `shared_ptr` when memory allocation fails. I'm looking for something that will work with GCC (libstdc++), Clang (libc++) and MSVC.

Current idea: Put some upper bound on the size of control block, and only call `allocate_shared` if enough memory could be preallocated (for control block plus object).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your constructors never throw, since you are in a "no exception"-environment. The same has to be true for your Allocators then. Then according to [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared), `allocate_shared()` will not throw. An empty `shared_ptr` is exactly the same as a `shared_ptr`, so there is no need to create any wrapper or something here.

So yes, you can use it, though I'd recommend to try and get that "no exception"-restriction away. I have never ever found a really good reason for such a restriction anywhere.

Comment: You are inferring too much from the documentation. Standard allocators aren't supposed to return `nullptr`, so `allocate_shared()` doesn't account for this situation. In practice, you will get illegal access instead of an empty `shared_ptr`.

Comment: `allocate_shared()` should not have to account for that situation. I guess, you want to be sure, that the constructor is never called on null-pointers. Well, `allocate_shared()` will use `allocator_traits<MyAlloc>::construct()`. So just specialize the `allocator_traits` for your custom allocator and you'll be fine.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way but according to N4140 §20.8.2.2.6: `allocate_shared` _allocates memory suitable for an object of type T and constructs an object in that memory
via the placement new expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`_.

Comment: I see, though I think, that defeats the purpose of `allocator_traits<>` somehow. Of course `allocate_shared()` can fullfill that requirement by using `allocator_traits<>::construct()`, that will do a placement new, but I understand, that that is not required. Hm, looks like you'll have to write your own variant of `allocate_shared()` then. I think, that that is a flaw in the standard.

Comment: Actually, even if `allocator_traits<>::construct()` were guaranteed to be used it wouldn't be enough. The traits would need to be specialized for some unknown type (whatever library uses for control block + object). And `allocate_shared()` would still need awareness of `nullptr` case to prevent creation of control block.

Comment: I thought, you are implementing your own allocator. Then you can specialize `allocator_traits<>` for it and your are done. If that is not the case, how do you know, the allocator will return a null pointer in case of failure and not do something undefined, because it tries to throw, with exceptions disabled in the compiler?

Comment: What I mean is even with a custom allocator to control both allocation and construction, `allocate_shared()` can't be used as-is.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The last few comments were more a hypothetical discussion then.

Comment: BTW.: We'll get what I assumed with the next C++ standard: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2070